# Send props In Field react final form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form, react-final-form-arrays

I have this Field in my react final form, i need to pass setstate to storage files before submit the form.

```
<Field name={`item_lateral[${index}].image_lateral[0].path_image_lateral`}>
       {props => (                                                       
             <div>
             <ImageInput {...props} />
                 </div>
                  )
                  }

               </Field>
```

I am using this link [example Form](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-shtern-pcg1tz?file=/src/App.js) to create my customField, but i need pass more props, like setLateralImages, setNewImage, but i can not how to do it....

Someone can help me?
THanks

Comment: The code didn't work on codeSandbox

Comment: Now works again.